# Which file is the theme index page?

Tags: homepage

I'm new to wordpress, and I want to edit the **homepage** of a theme. I just could not find out which file should I be editing with. I've tried to remove *page.php*, *index.php*, *single.php* under /wp-content/themes/mytheme, but my site is still working after I removed all these files, so which file is the theme actually using as the homepage?

I'm using wordpress 4.8, wooCommerce 3.1

I'm using **Rosa** theme, and the files listed under the theme root are these,
index.php, page.php, single.php, sidebar.php, functions.php, footer.php, comments.php header.php

Comment: This highly depends both on a theme and configuration. I would recommend to contact theme’s support.

Comment: which theme you are using

Comment: @ManojDeswal I'm using Rosa theme.

Comment: what you want to edit.I mean which part?

Comment: @VasimVanzara The layout. I want to add a sidebar menu that displays my woocommerce categories on the theme homepage.

Comment: ok you can edit using page templte

Comment: /rosa/page-templates/page-no-title.php

Comment: file,is it working?

Comment: @VasimVanzara I tried to edit the page-no-title.php, and cleared cache. but nothing happens on the frontpage. Are we sure this is where homdpage get loaded?

Comment: Your homepage is created in a admin area.This is template where you can add thing as you want

Comment: You could check if a child theme is active. In that case you would have to edit the files in that theme folder. If your site runs even if you removed all main files it seems you are editing in the wrong theme folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The homepage template depends on two things:

1. What the "Front page displays" setting has been set to.
2. Which files exist in the theme.

The WordPress [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) shows how WordPress decides which theme file to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using child theme then parent theme index.php will get called.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/140687)

Comment: I've modified the answer. How much reputation do I need to coment on any post?

Comment: 50 rep will let you comment everywhere. A listing of all of the privileges with their required rep is available in the [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).